# DraggableScrollableSheet with Navigator

Tags: flutter

I want to start discussion here about the DraggableScrollableSheet and how to possibly use it with nested Navigator.

The problem is simple and problematic at the same time.

Here is an example code:
First I have an Draggable Scrollable with custom Stateful widget MyCustomTabs

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
                
                  builder: (context, scrollController) => Column(
                    children: [
                 
                      Expanded(child: MyCustomTabs(
                        key: myCustomTabsKey,
                        scrollController: scrollController,)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Secondly this is an implementation of MyCustomTabs

```
class MyCustomTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  final ScrollController scrollController;
  const MyCustomTabs({Key? key, required this.scrollController})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyCustomTabs> createState() => MyCustomTabsState();
}

class MyCustomTabsState extends State<MyCustomTabs> {

  int _page = 1;

  set page(int value){
    setState((){
      _page = value;
    });
    print("set new great sttea");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      pages: [
        if(_page == 1)
          MaterialPage(
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: widget.scrollController,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              color: Color(0xFF41DACC),
            ),
          ),
        )),
        if(_page == 2)
          MaterialPage(
              child: ListView.builder(
                //THIS WILL CREATE AN ERROR
                controller: widget.scrollController,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 200,
                    color: Color(0xFFAB27AF),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This setup will cause an error if we try to attach scroll controller to different ListView widgets.

So Now I will try to solve this problems with use of notifications and my custom Scroll controllers pair.
One of which will send notifications about a scroll and the second will receive notifications from child widgets and pass it to DraggableScrollable

Or maybe there is another solution out of the box.